# Propagator of four-dimensional Chern-Simons theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, gauge-theory, correlation-functions, chern-simons-theory

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03601, on page 13, the propagator of 4d Chern-Simons theory is computed, in the gauge $D^iA_i=0$, where $D^i = (\partial_x,\partial_y,4\partial_z)$.

The gauge-fixed action is
$$\begin{equation}
S + S_{\text{gf}} 
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{M}d^4w\,
\Bigg(\varepsilon^{ijk}\textrm{Tr}\bigg(A_i\partial_jA_k + \frac{2}{3}A_iA_jA_k\bigg)
-\xi^{-1}\textrm{Tr}\Big((D^iA_i)^2\Big)\Bigg)\,,
\end{equation}\tag{3.1}$$
where $\xi$ is a gauge-fixing parameter. The propagator $\Delta_{ij}(w,w')$ on $M$ satisfies
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi}(\varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_j + \xi^{-1}D^iD^k)\Delta_{k\ell}(w,w') 
= c\,\delta^i_{\,\ell}\,\delta^{(4)}(w-w')\,,
\end{equation}\tag{3.2}$$
where $c=t_a\otimes t_b\,(\kappa^{-1})^{ab} \, = t_a\otimes t^a \in \mathfrak{g}^{\otimes 2}$, where the Killing form is $\kappa_{ab}=\textrm{Tr}(t_at_b)$.  In Landau gauge ($\xi=0$), the propagator is claimed to be
$$\begin{equation}
\label{PropagatoronM}
\Delta_{ij}(w,w') = -\frac{c}{4\pi}\varepsilon_{ijk}D^k\bigg(\frac{1}{\|w-w'\|^2}\bigg) = -\frac{c}{4\pi}\varepsilon_{ijk}D^k\bigg(\frac{1}{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')(\bar{z}-\bar{z}')}\bigg) \,.
\end{equation}\tag{3.3}$$

Away from $w=w'$, this is obvious from the antisymmetry of the Levi-Civita tensor. However, it is not clear to me why this is the case for $w=w'$. In fact, by computing $D^k\Delta_{kl}$ explicitly, I obtain zero. What am I missing?

Comment: I am perhaps not keeping up  with the recent trends, but afaik Chern-Simons theory exists only in odd numbers of dimensions. The action you wrote doesn't make sense, you seem to be integrating a 3-form over a 4-manifold. In the paper you link I think the manifold is 3d, not 4d.

Comment: 4d Chern-Simons theory is well-defined, just that it’s not topological but topological-holomorphic, a nice review by Witten is https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.00592

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4369147/11127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is enough to consider the quadratic part of abelian Chern-Simons (CS) Lagrangian density in [$R_{\xi}$-gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R.CE.BE_gauges)
   $${\cal L}_2 
   ~=~ \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{ijk}A_i\partial_j A_k 
   -\frac{1}{2\xi}(D^iA_i)^2. \tag{A}$$
   The propagator
   $$ \Delta_{k\ell}(w)~=~\underbrace{\Delta^{(0)}_{k\ell}(w)}_{\text{Landau gauge}}
   +\xi \Delta^{(1)}_{k\ell}(w)\tag{B}$$
   should satisfy
   $$\begin{align}
   \varepsilon^{ijk}&\partial_j\Delta^{(0)}_{k\ell}(w) + D^iD^k\Delta^{(1)}_{k\ell}(w)\cr
   ~=~&\left(\varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_j + \xi^{-1}D^iD^k\right)\Delta_{k\ell}(w)\cr 
   ~=~&\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 
   4\pi\delta^i_{\ell}\delta^3(w)&{\rm for}&d=3, \cr
   4\pi^2\delta^i_{\ell}\delta^4(w)&{\rm for}&d=4. \end{array}\right.
   \end{align}\tag{C}$$
2. *Remark:* The CS level and the Lie algebra color factors only contribute by an overall normalization, which we have ignored for simplicity. Also we have taken the liberty to change other normalization conventions. It is straightforward to restore these.
3. Warm-up: The $d=3$ Euclidean propagator:
   $$\begin{align} \Delta^{(0)}_{k\ell}(w)
   ~=~&-\varepsilon_{k\ell m} D^m\frac{1}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{1/2}}\cr
   ~=~&\varepsilon_{k\ell m} \frac{w^m}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}},\end{align}\tag{D}$$
   $$\begin{align} 2\Delta^{(1)}_{k\ell}(w)~=~&-\partial_k\partial_{\ell}(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{1/2}\cr
   ~=~&-\partial_k\frac{w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{1/2}}\cr
   ~=~&-\frac{\delta_{k\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{1/2}}+\frac{w_kw_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}}.
   \end{align}\tag{E}$$
   Here the regularization $\epsilon>0$ is an infinitesimal parameter.
4. *Sketched proof of the $d=3$ case:*
   $$\begin{align} 
   \varepsilon^{ijk}&\partial_j\Delta^{(0)}_{k\ell}(w)\cr
   ~=~&\varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon_{k\ell m} \partial_j\frac{w^m}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}}\cr
   ~=~&\left(\delta^i_{\ell}\delta^j_m- (i\leftrightarrow j) \right) \left(\frac{\delta^m_j}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}} -\frac{3 w^m w_j}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{5/2}}\right)\cr
   ~=~&\frac{3\epsilon\delta^i_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{5/2}} -\frac{\delta^i_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}} +\frac{3 w^i w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{5/2}}\cr
   ~=~&\underbrace{\frac{3\epsilon\delta^i_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{5/2}}}_{=~4\pi\delta^i_{\ell} \delta^3(w)} -D^i\frac{w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}} , 
   \end{align}\tag{F}$$
   $$\begin{align} D^iD^k&\Delta^{(1)}_{k\ell}(w)\cr
   ~=~&D^i\left(\frac{5w_{\ell}}{2(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}}-\frac{3|w|^2w_{\ell}}{2(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{5/2}}\right)\cr
   ~=~&D^i\left(\frac{w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}}+\underbrace{\frac{3\epsilon w_{\ell}}{2(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{5/2}}}_{=~0}\right).\end{align}\tag{G}$$
   Here we have [represented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function)$^1$ the 3D [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) as a [generalized function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function).
   $\Box$
5. OP's question: The $d=4$ Euclidean propagator:
   $$\begin{align} \Delta^{(0)}_{k\ell}(w)
   ~=~&-\varepsilon_{k\ell m} D^m\frac{1}{|w|^2+\epsilon}\cr
   ~=~&\varepsilon_{k\ell m} \frac{2W^m}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2},\end{align}\tag{H}$$
   $$\begin{align} 4\Delta^{(1)}_{k\ell}(w)
   ~=~& -\partial_k\partial_{\ell}\ln(|w|^2+\epsilon)
   \cr
   ~=~& -\frac{2\partial_k w_{\ell}}{|w|^2+\epsilon}
   +\frac{4w_kw_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2}.\end{align}\tag{I}$$
   Note the unusual definitions
   $$\begin{align} 
   \varepsilon^{xy\bar{z}}~=~&1~=~\varepsilon_{xy\bar{z}},\cr
   D^m~:=~&(\partial_x,\partial_y,4\partial_z), \cr
   \partial_j~:=~&(\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_{\bar{z}}),\cr
   \Box_w~:=~&\partial_jD^j~=~\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+4\partial_z\partial_{\bar{z}}, \cr
   W^m~:=~&\frac{1}{2}D^m|w|^2
   ~=~(x,y,2\bar{z}), \cr
   w_j~:=~&\frac{1}{2}\partial_j|w|^2
   ~=~(x,y,\frac{z}{2}),\cr
   |w|^2~:=~&x^2+y^2+z\bar{z}.
   \end{align}\tag{J}$$
   The unusual factor of 4 ensures that the linearized EOMs
   $$F_{xy}~\approx~0 , \qquad F_{x\bar{z}}~\approx~0 , \qquad F_{y\bar{z}}~\approx~0,\tag{K}$$
   become that the gauge fields $A_x$, $A_y$ & $A_{\bar{z}}$ each satisfy the wave equation with the Laplacian $\Box_w$, cf. Ref. 2.
6. *Sketched proof of the $d=4$ case:*
   $$\begin{align} 
   \varepsilon^{ijk}&\partial_j\Delta^{(0)}_{k\ell}(w)\cr
   ~=~&\varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon_{k\ell m} \partial_j\frac{2W^m}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2}\cr
   ~=~&\left(\delta^i_{\ell}\delta^j_m- (i\leftrightarrow j) \right) \left(\frac{2\partial_jW^m}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2} -\frac{8 W^m w_j}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^{3}}\right)\cr
   ~=~&\frac{8\epsilon\delta^i_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^3} -\frac{2\partial_{\ell}W^i}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2} +\frac{8 W^i w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^3}\cr
   ~=~&\underbrace{\frac{8\epsilon\delta^i_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^3}}_{=~4\pi^2\delta^i_{\ell} \delta^4(w)} -D^i\frac{2w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2}, 
   \end{align}\tag{L}$$
   $$\begin{align} D^iD^k&\Delta^{(1)}_{k\ell}(w)\cr
   ~=~&D^i\left(\frac{W^k\partial_k w_{\ell}+w_kD^kw_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2}\right.\cr
   &\left.+\frac{4w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2}
   -\frac{4|w|^2w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^3} \right)\cr
   ~=~&D^i\left(\frac{2w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^2}+\underbrace{\frac{4\epsilon w_{\ell}}{(|w|^2+\epsilon)^3}}_{=~0}\right).\end{align}\tag{M}$$
   $\Box$

References:

1. R. Bittleston & D. Skinner, [arXiv:1903.03601](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03601); eqs. (3.1)-(3.3).
2. K. Costello, E. Witten & M. Yamazaki, [arXiv:1709.09993](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.09993); eq. (4.4).

--

$^1$ See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3159739/11127) Math.SE post for a 1D example. Such representations generalize to any dimension. E.g. the 3D representation is proven in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/251194/2451).

Comment: Notes for later: In (perturbatively defined) 4D holomorphic CS theory with covariant derivative $D=d+A$, we must have inverse length dimension $[S/\hbar]=0$, $[A]=1$ and $[\hbar]=-1$. The standard perturbative normalization of the gauge field is $\tilde{A}_{\mu}=A_{\mu}/\sqrt{\hbar}$. It has inverse length dimension $[\tilde{A}_{\mu}] = 3/2$. The coupling constant $[\sqrt{\hbar}]=-1/2<0$ has negative inverse length dimension, i.e. it is [superficially non-renormalizable by naive power-counting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481249/2451), and has IR-irrelevant couplings.

Comment: Nevertheless, the theory is perturbatively renormalizable as follows. Any gauge-invariant effective action (counter) term must depend on $F$ and therefore vanishes on-shell, and hence can be removed by (perturbative local) field redefinitions. Since the $S$-matrix is independent of field redefinitions, the theory is in fact IR free!

Comment: Notes for later: The $d=3$ case: Fourier transform $\quad \widetilde{\cal L}_2 =-\frac{1}{2} \widetilde{A}_i(-q) \left( -\varepsilon^{ijk}iq_j + \xi^{-1}Q^iQ^k \right) \widetilde{A}_k(q) + \widetilde{J}^k(-q) \widetilde{A}_k(q)$ $\sim\frac{1}{2} \widetilde{J}^k(-q) \widetilde{\Delta}_{k\ell}(q)\widetilde{J}^{\ell}(q)$; $\quad \widetilde{\Delta}_{k\ell}=\widetilde{\Delta}^{(0)}_{k\ell}+\xi\widetilde{\Delta}^{(1)}_{k\ell}$; $\quad \widetilde{\Delta}^{(0)}_{k\ell}=\varepsilon_{k\ell m} \frac{iq^m}{|q|^2}$; $\quad \widetilde{\Delta}^{(1)}_{k\ell}= \frac{q_kq_{\ell}}{(|q|^2)^2}$;

Comment: Notes for later: The $d=4$ case: We can define the 4d Fourier transform as usual $\quad\hat{f}(k_x,k_y,k,\bar{k}):=\int dxdy\frac{d\bar{z}dz}{2i}\exp\left\{-i(k_xx+k_yy+\frac{1}{2}\bar{k}z+\frac{1}{2}k\bar{z})\right\}$, but how to do it on triplet coordinates $(x,y,\bar{z})$?